# Lumen. Change url

Tags: php, lumen

Im working on a site wich i building in the Lumen framework.
My problem is the routing. It works fin as it is now, but i want the urls to look better.

Code:

routes.php

```
$app->get('/work/{id}', 'WorkController@getWork');
```

WorkController.php

```
public function getWork($id) {
    $project = DB::select("SELECT * FROM projects where id = $id");
    return view('work.index')->with('project', $project);
}
```

Its a portfolio-like site where i want to get a specifik db-post by its id.
But i want the urls to look better. Now the urls looks like: `www.site.com/work/2` where 2 is the id. How can i instead for example use the db-posts title field as the url?

Answer (score 0):

You could store a urltitle column in each row of the project table. This would hold a String identifier of the project. For example you could convert the project title to lower case and replace each space with a dash. (You would also have to deal with special characters)

Your route would look like this:

```
$app->get('/work/{urltitle}', 'WorkController@getWork');
```

And your query would look like this:

```
public function getWork($urltitle) {
    $project = DB::select("SELECT * FROM projects where urltitle = $urltitle");
    return view('work.index')->with('project', $project);
}
```

An example of the new url would be `www.mysite.com/work/my-first-project`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! Im aware of that, i just done think its clean enough. I want to achieve the same thing without having to add an extra field. I want to use the existing fields and somehow parse it in php.

Comment: That would mean you would have to do some sort of extra computation on each request. For example you could do what I suggested on the fly using the mysql string functions but that would slow down the query http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html. You would also have to generate the links each time the user loads the page. It would be a great deal simpler to store the uri segment and query against it. Unless there is a specific reason you can't do it. I think that the extra column is the cleanest option.